# MySQL join query or sub query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a query that selects `mike` if it isn't in the three highest bids for a keyword. Rows 4 and 7 should be selected.

So in final, if mike isn't in the three highest bids for a keyword, then select.

How do I solve this? With a sub query?

```
$construct = "SELECT child.* FROM `temp-advertise` child
    LEFT JOIN `temp-advertise` parent on child.keyword=parent.keyword
    WHERE child.name='mike'
    ORDER BY child.id DESC";

 id  |  name| keyword    | bid   |
   1 |  mike|  one       |  7    |
   2 |  tom |  one       |  4    |
   3 |  ced |  one       |  6    |
   4 |  mike|  two       |  1    |
   5 |  tom |  two       |  5    |
   6 |  har |  two       |  5    |
   7 |  mike|  one       |  3    |
   8 |  har |  two       |  3    |
```

Comment: by "top 3" bids, I'm assuming bid is ex: $ and you want the highest 3 bids and se if Mike is one of the top 3?  Also, this looks like a subset of bids... what is basis of bid ex: for the $ reference?

Comment: yes,  if `mike` isn't in the 3 highest bids for a keyword, then select.

Comment: So, its on top 3 PER KEYWORD...  Mike has 3 entries, 2 of them on keyword "one".  How do we know who has best bid is... your table shows ID 1 with a bid of 7 for keyword "one", then a lower bid ID=7, bid=3 which is lower. I wouldn't expect a newer entry to allow for a lower bid amount. Also, specific name "mike", what about "mike X" and "mike Y", how do you know which "mike"is meant... any customer ID associated instead of just name?

Comment: you can bid on the same keyword 3 times, as there are three advert spaces available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `temp-advertise` ta
WHERE   ta.keyword = 'one'
        AND ta.name = 'mike'
        AND ta.bid <
        (
        SELECT  bid
        FROM    `temp-advertise` tai
        WHERE   tai.keyword = 'one'
        ORDER BY
                bid DESC
        LIMIT 2, 1
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select ID, name, keyword from temp-advertise e
    where 3 <= (select count(name) from temp-advertise
        where e.keyword = keyword and bid > e.bid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure doesn't look too promising, nor your sample data. However, that said, you want to know if "Mike" was in the top 3 per keyword... and that he has 3 bids.... 2 for "one", 1 for "two".  From the raw data, it looks like Mike is in 1st place and 4th place for the "one" keyword, and 4th place for "two" keyword.

This should get you what you need with SOME respect to not doing a full query of all keywords.  The first innermost query is to just get keywords bid on by "mike" (hence alias "JustMike").  Then join that to the temp-advertise on ONLY THOSE keywords.

Next, by using MySQL variables, we can keep track of the rank PER KEYWORD.  The trick is the ORDER BY clause needs to return them in the order that represents proper ranking.  In this case, each keyword first, then within each keyword, ordered by highest bid first.

By querying the records, then using the @variables, we increase the counter, start at 1 every time the keyword changes, then preserve the keyword into the @grpKeyword variable for comparison of the next record.  Once ALL bids are processed for the respective keywords, it then queries THAT result but ONLY for those bid on by "mike".  These records will have whatever his rank position was.

```
select RankPerKeyword.*
   from
      ( SELECT ta.*,
               @grpCnt := if( @grpKeyword = ta.Keyword, @grpCnt +1, 1 ) as KWRank,
               @grpKeyword := ta.Keyword as carryForward
           FROM 
              ( select distinct ta1.keyword
                   from `temp-advertise` ta1
                   where ta1.name = "mike" ) as JustMike
                 JOIN `temp-advertise` ta
                    on JustMike.Keyword = ta.Keyword,
              ( select @grpCnt := 0,
                       @grpKeyword := '' ) SqlVars
           ORDER BY 
              ta.Keyword,
              ta.Bid DESC" ) RankPerKeyword
   where
     RankPerKeyword.name = "mike"
```

(Run above to just preview the results... should show 3 records)

So, if you want to know if it was WITHIN the top 3 for a keyword you could just change to

```
select RankPerKeyword.keyword, MIN( RankPerKeyword.KWRank ) as BestRank
  from (rest of query)
  group by RankPerKeyword.Keyword
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
SELECT .. ORDER BY bid LIMIT 3,999
```